# Can the value of heritability be greater than 1?

Tags: genetics, evolution, population-genetics, natural-selection, evolutionary-game-theory

Heritability defined as genetic variance divided by total variance seems to be bounded between 0 and 1.  However, I see a way of calculating heritability on this page (http://www.radford.edu/~rsheehy/Gen_flash/Tutorials/Linear_Regression/reg-tut.htm) with:  2*Covxy / Varx.  However, a result calculated in this way could be greater than 1.  What am I missing?

Comment: I am missing where on that site it is stated the formula you are giving is calculating heritability.

Comment: Where it says "Calculating the slope," but I multiply by 2 for a sexual population, according to the last paragraph on the page.

Comment: @skymningen It's at the bottom: "Regression of offspring on only one parent underestimates narrow-sense heritability by about 50%. Therefore, Christine's analysis suggested a narrow-sense heritability of 2 x 0.414 = 0.828." The problem is that if you had both parents, the slope would be closer to 0.828, and it wouldn't be doubled.